# Unable to log received SNMPv3 traps

Tags: snmpv3

I am sending snmpv3 traps out using app 'snmptrap' and not able to see the traps on trap-receiver side (snmptrapd) only for snmpv3-user whose security level is noAuthNoPriv . 
 Below mentioned are my test details.

### Details:

system1: ip=172.16.1.214, sends snmpv3 trap to 'system2' using 'snmptrap

system2: ip=172.16.1.131, has 'snmptrapd' running and receives trap messages and logs it

## System1: sending two SNMPv3  trap out

# snmptrap -v 3 -n "" **-l noAuthNoPriv** -u trapuser1 -e 0x0123456789010384
 172.16.1.131 69 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1 i 13

# snmptrap -v 3 -n "" -a SHA -A mypassword **-l authNoPriv** -u trapuser2 -e 0x0123456789010384 localhost 69 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1 i 14

## System2: Trap-receiver

> ~$cat /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf
>
> createUser -e 0x0123456789010384 trapuser1
>   createUser -e 0x0123456789010384 trapuser2 SHA mypassword
>   authUser log trapuser1
>   **authUser log trapuser2**

**~$snmptrapd -c /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf**

---

NET-SNMP version 5.4.3  NET-SNMP version 5.4.3

usm: usm: USM processing begun...
USM processing begun...
usm: usm: match on user trapuser1  **<---- (comment) trapuser1 has noauth no encrypt (/comment)**
match on user trapuser1
usm: usm: USM processing completed.
USM processing completed.    **< ---   (comment) received trap not got logged (/comment)**

> Question: why snmptrapd not able to log the received trap for snmpv3 user(trapuser1) which has noAuthNoPriv, though config file has 'authUser log trapuser1'?

usm: usm: USM processing begun...
USM processing begun...
usm: usm: match on user trapuser2   **<---(comment)trapuser2 has only auth (/comment)**
match on user trapuser2
usm: usm: Verification succeeded.
Verification succeeded.
usm: usm: USM processing completed.
USM processing completed.
2014-12-10 21:41:07 localhost [UDP: [127.0.0.1]:36661->[127.0.0.1]]:
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (69) 0:00:00.69    iso.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 14
2014-12-10 21:41:07 localhost [UDP: [127.0.0.1]:36661->[127.0.0.1]]:
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (69) 0:00:00.69    iso.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 14  **<-- (comment) received trap got logged (/comment)**

---

Comment: I think more detail is needed here. It's unclear exactly what you're doing, so it's similarly hard to give an answer.

Comment: @Sobrique: Added more description. Let me know for any information